# How to refresh only the updated item in a list, using useQuery() to get the list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, react-query

I retrieve a list of jobs using useQuery(), each one have a Favourite icon (filled depending if it's favourited)
If I click that button, I managed to refresh the item Favourite icon, but it refreshes all the items.
Whats the correct way to avoid that? Because it appears the Loading wheel again, and I think it has to be a more elegant way.

```
const Openings = () => {
    const onToggleFav = () => {
        setFavCount(prev => prev + 1)
    }

    const [favCount, setFavCount] = useState(0);
    const { isLoading, data } = useQuery(
        ['getRecruiterOpenings', favCount],
        () => getRecruiterOpenings()
    );

    return (
        <div>
            { isLoading ? <Loading /> : (
                <>
                    { data && data.openings && data.openings.map((opening) => (
                        <>
                            <Opening {...opening} onToggleFav={() => onToggleFav()} key={opening.id}/>
                        </>
                    ))}
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Openings;
```

Inside Opening component I have a method that dispatches when you click the fav icon:

```
const toggleFav = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await toggleFavOpening(fav, id).then(() => {
        if(onToggleFav) onToggleFav()
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand that code. whenever you click on any of the `Openings`, you increment a count, which will create a new query key, but then favCount is not passed to getRecruiterOpenings ... Also not really sure what you _want_ to achieve to be honest. I'm guessing that the key change is what triggers a refetch, but that seems unwanted? I'm also missing a mutation of some sorts that actually updates the backend and tells it to update the favourite icon ...

Comment: The code is not complete, just for focus on which is important. I can add it if it makes easier to understand.
`favCount` is only for refetching data, it's something that I didn't like, but it's the way I found to update the DOM. 
What is unwanted is refreshing all items, when it only changes the one I clicked. That makes sense? has React a way to refresh only the one I changed? You mention mutation, maybe thats the way to go, using `useMutation()` and when succeed update the cache state, avoiding refetch and refresh. I don't know if it's the best practice.

Comment: yes, that would be an update from a mutation response: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/updates-from-mutation-responses